# Анализ художественных текстов

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Мне стало интересно, анализируют ли с помощью нейронных сетей художественную литературу и какие задачи перед собой ставят. Например: определение характеров героев произведений, конфликтов между героями, выявление сюжета произведения. В интернете ничего подобного не нашел. Можете плз покидать какие нибуть ссылки по данной теме?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых самая главная [ссылка](https://www.google.ru/) которая помогает всегда и везде)) Дальше по поводу вашего вопроса - есть разница между анализом текста, [аналитикой](https://monkeylearn.com/text-analytics/) и [интеллектуальным анализом текста](https://monkeylearn.com/text-mining/). Довольно часто в сети встречаются случаи когда AI ставили задачу - критика текста. Так же искусственный интеллект [анализирует](https://monkeylearn.com/sentiment-analysis/) чувства героев. Это все алгоритмы которые закладывают в процессе обучения. Анализируют так же тему текста, определяют язык (как например гугл переводчик). Есть сети которые помогают компаниям в анализировании фидбека от клиентов ([ссылка](https://app.monkeylearn.com/main/classifiers/cl_v9GTn7zi/)). [Ищут](https://app.monkeylearn.com/main/extractors/ex_YCya9nrn/) ключевые слова например тоже при помощи обученной AI. [Вот](https://app.monkeylearn.com/main/extractors/ex_94WD2XxD/) например сеть дает вытяжку из абзаца текста, то есть создает аналог данного ей текста только более сжатый. [Вот](https://monkeylearn.com/text-analysis/) короче БОЛЬШАЯ статья в которой написано довольно много интересного по вашему вопросу. Еще [ссылка_1](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frobt.2019.00053/full), [ссылка_2](https://www.wired.com/story/nanogenmo-ai-novels-gpt2/) и [ссылка_3](https://aeon.co/essays/how-ai-is-revolutionising-the-role-of-the-literary-critic). Надеюсь это поможет в решении вашего вопроса.

Comment: Кроме всего прочего попадались помню исследования, которые строили графы связей между героями произведения.